# How to set a Stage in java FX8 always show override on another stage

Tags: javafx-8

I have two stage. first stage set to full-Screen and have a button to call second stage,the second Stage I design same as dialog confirm . when I call second stage I want it always show override on first stage (currently. second stage was show and when I click on first stage then first stage override on second stage)

please help me.
thank!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the second stage to be always on top of the first stage.

You can achieve the same by setting `stage.initOwner()` along with `Modality.WINDOW_MODAL` to your second stage :

```
stage.initOwner(firstStage);
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

Comment: I tried but not apply, please tell me another method. thank!